# How I can serialize/de-serialize a list of Integers? Is it possible with this library to do that with Quirk?

Tags: java, csv

Yo.

I'm trying out this new CSV Library Quirk CSV. I've used it for primitive objects, but I'm trying to figure out how I can serialize/de-serialize a list of Integers. Is this possible with Quirk?

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            CSVProcessor<Client> parser = new CSVProcessor<>(Client.class);
            String header = "ID,NAME,AGENTS\n";
            String data = "1,client,2|4|66";
            List<Client> list = parser.parse(new StringReader(header+data), CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withIgnoreHeaderCase());
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            parser.write(list,sw,CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
            System.out.println(sw);
        }
    
        @CSVReadComponent(type = CSVType.NAMED)
        @CSVWriteComponent(type = CSVType.NAMED)
        public static class Client{
    
            @CSVReadBinding(header = "id")
            @CSVWriteBinding(header = "id")
            private long id;
    
            @CSVReadBinding(header = "name")
            @CSVWriteBinding(header = "name")
            private String name;
            
    
            @CSVReadBinding(header = "agents")
            @CSVWriteBinding(header = "agents")
            private List<Integer> agentIds;
            // Getters & Setters
            
        }

,,,
```

Comment: I’m not familiar with that library, but I would expect this to work: `String data = "1,client,\"2,4,66\"";` or if not then this: `String data = "1,client,[2,4,66]";` or `String data = "1,client,\"[2,4,66]\"";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see someone using this.

I'm the developer of [Quirk-CSV](https://github.com/bpoole6/quirk-csv). This use case isn't too bad to solve. You can use an inline wrapper like so:

```
 @CSVReadBinding(header = "agents", wrapper = AgentsReadWrapper.class)
 @CSVWriteBinding(header = "agents", wrapper = AgentsWriteWrapper.class)
 private List<Integer> agentIds;



public static class AgentsReadWrapper implements ReadWrapper<List<Integer>> {

    @Override
    public List<Integer> apply(String str) {
        if(Objects.isNull(str) || str.trim().isEmpty()){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\|"))
                .map(String::trim)
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

public static class  AgentsWriteWrapper implements WriteWrapper<List<Integer>>{

    @Override
    public String apply(List<Integer> str) {
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("|");
        str.stream().map(String::valueOf).forEach(sj::add);
        return sj.toString();
    }
}
```

If you have any problems you can also post issues on the repository as well. I'll try to answer them as quickly as possible for you.

Comment: I solved it the other day :D

However, this is essentially what I did so +1 for you. Thanks for taking the time to help m8 - much appreciated.